# Using temporary, Using filesort with order and group by

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, sql-order-by

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM table11
WHERE table1.field1 = 1
GROUP BY table1.field2
ORDER BY table1.field3 DESC
```

I tried all these

```
(field1,field2,field3)
(field1,field3,field2)
```

indexes but still explain plan shows using temporary and using filesort.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort the data by **field3** which is not part of **group by** clause. This means that **field3** participates in the process of grouping which returns random values of **field3**, so the filesort is inevitable.

In this case the best possible index is `(field1, field2)`.